# Can PagedList be used to automatically switch pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net-mvc and I have a PageList from https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList in my project, it works fine but I would like to be able to switch the pages automatically on a set time interval. The pages I am using have a set number of accordion items and wanted to know how I could switch the page number without human interaction. Like use a slideshow with pagedList. Is there something better to use or is this possible?

My Index.cshtml

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ComputerDownTimeTracker.Models.DashboardTicketListVM>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<body>

<div class="list1">
    <div id="accordion">

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
           <div class="header">

                <b> Equipment: </b>@item.ComputerName <br />
                <b> Location: </b>@item.Location

                @switch (item.RunningStatus)
                {
                    case 1: imagePath = down;
                        break;
                    case 2: imagePath = running;
                        break;
                    case 3: imagePath = waiting;
                        break;
                    case 4: imagePath = waiting;
                        break;
                    default: imagePath = running;
                        break;
                }
                <img class="status" src="@imagePath" alt="" />


                <ul class="timeStat">

                    <li><b class="time">Computer Down At :</b> @item.OnClickTimeStamp</li>


                    @if (@item.RunningStatus == 4)
                    {
                        <li> <b class="time"> Maintenance On issue :</b> @item.EditTimeStamp</li>
                    }
                    @if (@item.RunningStatus == 3)
                    {
                        <li> <b class="time">Waiting For Parts :</b> @item.EditTimeStamp</li>
                    }
                    @if (@item.RunningStatus == 2)
                    {
                        <li> <b class="time">Computer Restarted :</b> @item.EditTimeStamp</li>
                    }
                </ul>

            </div>@*//computer name and status div*@

            <div><p>@Html.Raw(@item.ComputerStatus)</p></div>

        }


        @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",new { page }))

    </div>

</div>
```

My Home controller index method

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        var time = DateTime.Now;
        time = time.AddSeconds(-100); 

        var ViewModel = _ComputerDB.Database.SqlQuery<DashboardTicketListVM>(listQuery).ToList();

        var remove_running = ViewModel.Where(x => x.OnRestartTimeStamp >= time || x.OnRestartTimeStamp == null);

        int pageSize = 8;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);


        return View("Index", "~/Views/Shared/_ListLayout.cshtml", remove_running.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

I omitted a lot of stuff that wasn't really relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use use Javascript [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to reload the next page after some specified time.

Using the [PagedList](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList) examples:

## Controller

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public object Index(int? page)
    {
        var products = MyProductDataSource.FindAllProducts(); //returns IQueryable<Product> representing an unknown number of products. a thousand maybe?

        var pageNumber = page ?? 1; // if no page was specified in the querystring, default to the first page (1)
        var onePageOfProducts = products.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25); // will only contain 25 products max because of the pageSize

        ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts = onePageOfProducts;
        return View();
    }
}
```

## View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Product Listing"
}
@using PagedList.Mvc; //import this so we get our HTML Helper
@using PagedList; //import this so we can cast our list to IPagedList (only necessary because ViewBag is dynamic)

<!-- import the included stylesheet for some (very basic) default styling -->
<link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- loop through each of your products and display it however you want. we're just printing the name here -->
<h2>List of Products</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach(var product in ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts){
        <li>@product.Name</li>
    }
</ul>

<!-- output a paging control that lets the user navigation to the previous page, next page, etc -->
@Html.PagedListPager( (IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }) )
```

## View Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nextPage = @(((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts.PageNumber) + 1); // next page number is current page number + 1
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = "index?page=" + nextPage; // load new page after timeout
    }, (5 * 1000) /* set timeout here, example: 5 seconds */);
</script>
```

Note: You may need to add some additional logic to make sure to stop the next page loading whenever you get to the end of your pages. You can do this by checked the `HasNextPage` property provided by PagedList.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hasNextPage = @(((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts.HasNextPage) ? "true" : "false");

    if(hasNextPage) {
        var nextPage = @(((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts.PageNumber) + 1); // next page number is current page number + 1
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location = "index?page=" + nextPage; // load new page after timeout
        }, (5 * 1000) /* set timeout here, example: 5 seconds */);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, getting an error 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'True' is undefined.

Comment: Not really understanding this, I am trying to use a model that has already been defined as an IPagedList with a javascript bool. I am getting the syntax wrong,        var hasNextPage = @((Model.HasNextPage) ? "true" : "false");

Comment: Got it to work with var hasNextPage = Boolean(@Model.HasNextPage.ToString().ToLower());

Comment: Great, hard to tell without seeing your model. Glad you got it working. Any other problems?